# Powershell: What is a good way to filter by json object property type [string] eg: "121 min" if/where -GE value [string]

Tags: powershell

I have a mixed format (txt/json) file that contains omdb movie info (1 movie per line) in the following format:

```
Starwars 1977 {JSON DATA}
The Matrix 1999 {JSON DATA}
The Terminator 1984 {JSON DATA}
```

So far I can load the file contents into a variable:

```
$movieInfoFile = (Get-Content -path .\movieinfo.txt)
```

Filter by line number:

```
$movieInfoFile[300] -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Filter by Actor:

```
$movieInfoFile -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object -Property Actors -CLike '*Harrison Ford*'`
```

Filter by Year:

```
$movieInfoFile -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object -Property Year -GE '1999'
```

I want to filter by 'Runtime' being greater than let's say '121 min'...

I tried this...

```
$movieInfoFile -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object -Runtime -GE '121 min'
```

But it doesn't work. There is no error message, it just doesn't filter at all so I end up with everything. I'm guessing it's because the value is a string and I am trying to treat it like an integer.

So I created the following foreach loop while I was formulating this question and it works...

```
foreach ($line in $movieInfoFile) {
    [Int]$Rtime = ($line -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json).Runtime -replace(' min')
    IF ($Rtime -GE '160') {
        $line -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json
        }
}
```

So now I have a few questions please:

1. Is there a better way?
2. Could I have modified the original pipeline to get it to work?...

```
$movieInfoFile -replace('^[^{]*') | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object -Runtime -GE '121 min'
```

3. Why no error message with the original pipeline?

Thanks.

Here's a few lines from the movieinfo file to test with if needed...

```
12 Feet Deep 2016   {"Title":"12 Feet Deep","Year":"2017","Rated":"Not Rated","Released":"20 Jun 2017","Runtime":"85 min","Genre":"Horror, Thriller","Director":"Matt Eskandari","Writer":"Matt Eskandari, Michael Hultquist","Actors":"Nora-Jane Noone, Alexandra Park, Diane Farr","Plot":"Two sisters are trapped under the fiberglass cover of an Olympic sized public pool and must brave the cold and each other to survive the harrowing night.","Language":"English","Country":"United States","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOWM5ZWFmZTItMGVhMC00MGQwLTgzYzktOTIxMGY4YWVkZjYxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzk3OTY0OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"5.3/10"}],"Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"5.3","imdbVotes":"16,991","imdbID":"tt5143226","Type":"movie","DVD":"N/A","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
1984 1984   {"Title":"1984","Year":"1984","Rated":"R","Released":"22 Mar 1985","Runtime":"113 min","Genre":"Drama, Sci-Fi","Director":"Michael Radford","Writer":"Michael Radford, George Orwell","Actors":"John Hurt, Richard Burton, Suzanna Hamilton","Plot":"Longing for freedom, the lowly bureaucrat of the Ministry of Truth, Winston Smith, summons up the courage to write down his unspoken desires in his little secret diary. Serving silently at the pleasure of the grim, autocratic hyper-state of Oceania, Smith knows that the English Socialist Party's supreme leader, the omnipotent Big Brother, watches his every move, condemning the already terrified people into a life of slavery. Under those dire circumstances--as the totalitarian government's suffocating stranglehold tightens more and more--Julia, another equally seditious party member, crosses paths with Winston, and a dangerous clandestine affair begins. Now, there's no turning back, and, sooner or later, the illicit couple will have to pay for its hideous crimes against the dictatorial state. What makes a good citizen?","Language":"English","Country":"United Kingdom","Awards":"Nominated for 1 BAFTA Award6 wins & 3 nominations total","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMWFkNzIzNDUtNWI1Mi00ODA2LTgyMTMtYTZiYWMxMDFlNmNhL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAyODkwOQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"7.1/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"72%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"67/100"}],"Metascore":"67","imdbRating":"7.1","imdbVotes":"72,503","imdbID":"tt0087803","Type":"movie","DVD":"06 Oct 2013","BoxOffice":"$8,430,492","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
3 10 to Yuma 2007   {"Title":"3:10 to Yuma","Year":"2007","Rated":"R","Released":"07 Sep 2007","Runtime":"122 min","Genre":"Action, Crime, Drama","Director":"James Mangold","Writer":"Halsted Welles, Michael Brandt, Derek Haas","Actors":"Russell Crowe, Christian Bale, Ben Foster","Plot":"Rancher Dan Evans heads into Bisbee to clear up issues concerning the sale of his land when he witnesses the closing events of a stagecoach robbery led by famed outlaw Ben Wade. Shortly thereafter, Wade is captured by the law in Bisbee and Evans finds himself one of the escorts who will take Wade to the 3:10 to Yuma train in Contention for the reward of $200. Evans' effort to take Wade to the station is in part an effort to save his land but also part of an inner battle to determine whether he can be more than just a naive rancher in the eyes of his impetuous and gun slinging son William Evans. The transport to Contention is hazardous and filled with ambushes by Indians, pursuits by Wade's vengeful gang and Wade's own conniving and surreptitious demeanor that makes the ride all the more intense.","Language":"English, Chinese","Country":"United States","Awards":"Nominated for 2 Oscars. 3 wins & 32 nominations total","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODE0NTcxNTQzNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzczOTIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg","Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"7.7/10"},{"Source":"Rotten Tomatoes","Value":"89%"},{"Source":"Metacritic","Value":"76/100"}],"Metascore":"76","imdbRating":"7.7","imdbVotes":"311,097","imdbID":"tt0381849","Type":"movie","DVD":"08 Jan 2008","BoxOffice":"$53,606,916","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: Are all `Runtime` items in minutes with this format `XX min` ?

Comment: Thanks for the great response Theo. It answered my questions and showed me a much better approach. Yes, Runtime is XX min for all. I'm going to play with the code tonight to better understand it and explore some possibilities. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the data in the file to an array of objects, so you can filter on all of the properties.
To do that, try below

```
# read the file line-by line and convert it to become an array of PSObjects
$data = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\movies.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $movie,$json = ($_ -split '\s+{',2)
    $meta = "{$json" | ConvertFrom-Json
    # add the movie title identifier as a new property called 'Movie' to the metadata
    $meta | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Movie' -Value $movie

    # output this object to be collected in variable $data
    $meta
}
```

Now you can filter on all of the properties, so if you want movies by Runtime, just do:

```
$data | Where-Object { [int]($_.Runtime -replace '\D') -ge 121 }
```

Which, using your example would return this:

```
Title      : 3:10 to Yuma
Year       : 2007
Rated      : R
Released   : 07 Sep 2007
Runtime    : 122 min
Genre      : Action, Crime, Drama
Director   : James Mangold
Writer     : Halsted Welles, Michael Brandt, Derek Haas
Actors     : Russell Crowe, Christian Bale, Ben Foster
Plot       : Rancher Dan Evans heads into Bisbee to clear up issues concerning the sale of his land when he witnesses the closing events of a stage
             coach robbery led by famed outlaw Ben Wade. Shortly thereafter, Wade is captured by the law in Bisbee and Evans finds himself one of the escorts who will take Wade to the 3:10 to Yuma train in Contention for the reward of $200. Evans' effort to take Wade to the station is in part an effort to save his land but also part of an inner battle to determine whether he can be more than just a naive rancher
              in the eyes of his impetuous and gun slinging son William Evans. The transport to Contention is hazardous and filled with ambushes by
              Indians, pursuits by Wade's vengeful gang and Wade's own conniving and surreptitious demeanor that makes the ride all the more intense.
Language   : English, Chinese
Country    : United States
Awards     : Nominated for 2 Oscars. 3 wins & 32 nominations total
Poster     : https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODE0NTcxNTQzNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzczOTIzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg
Ratings    : {@{Source=Internet Movie Database; Value=7.7/10}, @{Source=Rotten Tomatoes; Value=89%}, @{Source=Metacritic; Value=76/100}}
Metascore  : 76
imdbRating : 7.7
imdbVotes  : 311,097
imdbID     : tt0381849
Type       : movie
DVD        : 08 Jan 2008
BoxOffice  : $53,606,916
Production : N/A
Website    : N/A
Response   : True
Movie      : 3 10 to Yuma 2007
```